# Ansible F5 Big-Ip list config

Tags: ansible, f5

How to list the network configuration of F5 BigIP load balancer using Ansible? I am able to fetch the pool list&members separately and vips as a separate list. But no, common item to match and loop over to get the output.

Expected output:

```
-Pool
   -Vip
     -members
```

Answer (score 1):

I am able to do this by using Jinja2 templates by combining both the lists and create a new JSON.
But I had to change the expected output to
-vip
-pool
-pool members

```
{
"items": {
     "vip": [
        {% for vip in jsondata['virtual_servers'] %}
        {
            "vipname": {{ vip | replace("u'", "\"") | replace("'", "\"") }},
            "poolname": "{{ vip['default_pool'].split('/')[-1] }}",
            {% for vipmembers in jsondata['ltm_pools'] %}
            {% set list1 = vip['default_pool'].split('/') %}
               {% if list1[-1] == vipmembers['name'] %}
                  "members": {{ vipmembers['members'] | replace("u'", "\"") | replace("'", "\"")}}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        },
        {% endfor %}
     ]
}
```

}